# Find intersections points with axes

Tags: list-manipulation, data

Let's create some points corresponding to a simple closed curve

```
C0 = ContourPlot[x^2/4 + y^2/9 == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 100];
data = C0[[1, 1]];
S0 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.005]}]
```

[image]

Now I would like to find the intersection points with the two axes. In this example the solutions should be $x = \pm 2$ and $y = \pm 3$.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** The real data file corresponds to a closed curve with unknown analytical equation, so in the suggested solution you should not take into account the equation of the ellipse, only `data` is known.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What version are you on? `C0[[1, 1]]` works for extracting points in old versions, but not in the new ones.

Comment: @J.M. I have v9.0.

Comment: @J.M. BTW, if I want to extract points in v10 what should I use?

Comment: @J.M. Actually `C0[[1,1]]` works just fine in v10.3: it extracts the actual coordinates of the points from the `GraphicsComplex` generated by `ContourPlot`.

Comment: @Marco, ah, right; nevertheless, it's not really the best way of extracting those points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of duplicate x values we can feed to an interpolation function

```
domain = Select[Tally[data[[All, 1]]], #[[2]] == 1 &][[All, 1]];
```

Create Interpolation functions and evaluate at 0
These are for the top and bottom halves of the fn

```
Interpolation[Select[data, #[[2]] < 0 && MemberQ[domain, #[[1]]] &]][0]
Interpolation[Select[data, #[[2]] > 0 && MemberQ[domain, #[[1]]] &]][0]

-2.99994
2.99994
```

Max and Min on the domain can approximate the x intercepts:

```
Max[domain]
Min[domain]

1.99985
-1.99985
```

### EDIT

Assuming your ellipse isn't 0-centered you will need exact x-intercepts

This requires a second domain and second set of interpolating functions, necessitating a transposition and reevaluation.

```
data2 = Reverse /@ data;
domain2 = Select[Tally[data2[[All, 1]]], #[[2]] == 1 &][[All, 1]];


Interpolation[Select[data2, #[[2]] < 0 && MemberQ[domain2, #[[1]]] &]][0]
Interpolation[Select[data2, #[[2]] > 0 && MemberQ[domain2, #[[1]]] &]][0]

-1.99996
1.99996
```

Comment: It works like a charm! However I think that the second `Max` and `Min` of the domain approximate the x intercepts, not y, right?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z correct! made the edit in the answer

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z please see the edit I made to actually solve for the x-intercepts, which will allow for your data to not be centered on 0